# Programmatically trigger the row-click event in q-table

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Is there a way to programmatically trigger the @row-click event on a given row in a q-table, using a method?

Comment: I don't know exactly but sounds like you need to add a "ref" on your table and try to access your row from there. Or if it's scoped-slot row, try to add a ref on it directly

Comment: Thanks David. I've tried with ref.I couldn't find a way to programmatically trigger a native event from the q-table.